# How to represent the linear transformation $T:X \to AX$ as a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A$ and $X$ be $n \times n$ real matrices. How do you express the linear transformation $T:X \to AX$ as a linear transformation over the $n^2$ bases vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$? Specifically, how does one compute the matrix representation of $T$?

Answer (score 3):

I started writing this before I realized how long it would be (lol).

The standard basis for the space of matrices consists of $E_{ij}$ where the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $1$ and all other entries are $0$. Now its easy to verify that $AE_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $j$-th column is is the $i$-th column of $A$. Thus, if we write the entries of $A$ as $a_{pq}$,
$$AE_{i,j}=a_{1,i}E_{1,j}+a_{2,i}E_{2,j}+\cdots+a_{n,i}E_{n,j}=\sum_{p=1}^na_{pi}E_{p,j}$$.

Now if we order the basis according to the entries starting at $1,1$ and going top-down and left-right, we get $E_{1,1},E_{2,1},\ldots,E_{n,1},E_{1,2},\ldots,E_{n,2},\ldots, E_{1,n},\ldots,E_{n,n}$. Then the first column (representing $AE_{1,1}$) will contain the first column of $A$ in the first $n$ positions. The second column (representing $AE_{2,1}$ will have the second column of $A$ in the first $n$ positions, etc. Continuing in this fashion, we see that the matrix will be a block diagonal $n^2\times n^2$ matrix whose $n\times n$ blocks are simply $A$.

---

As a check, let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}.$$
Our basis is then

$$E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

We compute

$$AE_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\3&0\end{pmatrix},\quad AE_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\4&0\end{pmatrix},\quad AE_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&3\end{pmatrix},\quad AE_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

and writing these as row vectors in our ordered basis

\begin{align}
AE_{11}&=E_{11}+3E_{21}=(1,3,0,0)\\
AE_{21}&=2E_{11}+4E_{21}=(2,4,0,0)\\
AE_{12}&=E_{12}+3E_{22}=(0,0,1,3)\\
AE_{22}&=2E_{12}+4E_{22}=(0,0,2,4).
\end{align}

The matrix for multiplication by $A$ is then

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty thing to do, but in the end, the matrices $X$ and $AX$ are simply vectors from $T$'s point of view. How you arrange the $n^2$ entries as a vector is up to you. It might be easier to list the action of $T$ on the basis matrices $(e_{ij})$ with a $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elswhere.

Comment: How nasty? It is not clear other than writing out a matrix multiplication.

Comment: How would your second suggestion work?

Comment: Nasty in the sense that the matrix of $T$ has $n^4$ entries. Depending on the structure of $A$ this can be arbitrary confusing. Better to gather all $e_{ij}\longrightarrow A\cdot e_{ij}$.

Comment: So A . e_ij would just get the ijth entry of A. We are the summing over all the i's and so you get $\sum_i A \cdot e_{ij}$?

Comment: We are summing over all i and j. As mentioned, the structure of A plays a significant role. If you have all entries given as $a_{ij}$, then you have $n^4$ matrix entries for $T$. They look similar in the general case, but with some given matrix $A$ or restrictions on where $X$ is taken from, things can be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult to write out the matrix for $T$, once you choose some nice notation. Let $E^{ij}$ denote the matrix with a 1 in the $(i, j)$ position and zeros elsewhere, which multiply like $E^{ij} E^{kl} = \delta_{jk} E^{il}$. These form a basis for the vector space $\operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb{R})$, so we should be able to write any linear operator $T \colon \operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb{R})$ down using this basis in the usual way: the matrix components $T_{ij, kl}$ are defined by the equation
$$ T(E^{kl}) = \sum_{i, j} T_{ij, kl} E^{ij}. $$
Now, for any matrix $A$ in $\operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb{R})$, let $[A]_{(i, j)} \in \mathbb{R}$ be the scalar in the $(i, j)$ place of the matrix. (I've used this weird notation to distinguish between the two different "levels" of matrices going on here). The defining equation above is saying that
$$ \left[ T(E^{kl}) \right]_{(i, j)} = T_{ij, kl},$$
or in other words, the "meta-matrix" entry $T_{ij, kl}$ is whatever is in the $(i, j)$ spot of the matrix $T(E^{kl}) \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Understanding the distinction between these two levels of matrix is essentially the whole problem.

Now fix a matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and define $T(X) = AX$. We can now write out what $T_{ij, kl}$ is using the definition of matrix multiplication:
$$ \begin{aligned}
T_{ij, kl}
  &= \left[T(E^{kl})\right]_{(i, j)} && \text{by discussion above} \\
  &= \left[A E^{kl}\right]_{(i, j)} && \text{by definition of } T\\
  &= \sum_{m} [A]_{(i, m)} \left[E^{kl}\right]_{(m, j)} && \text{by definition of matrix multiplication} \\
  &= [A]_{(i, k)} \delta_{lj} && \text{since } [E^{kl}]_{(m, j)} \text{ is 1 when } k = m \text{ and } l = j \text{, else } 0.
\end{aligned} $$
Therefore we can see that the matrix of $T$ is

$$T_{ix, ky} = \begin{cases} [A]_{(i, k)} & \text{if } x = y, \\ 0  & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

---

Can we get this result more quickly and less formally? Notice that $A E^{kl}$ is a matrix with a single nonzero column $l$, and that column is equal to the $k$th column of $A$. Written in equations this is
$$ T(E^{kl}) = A E^{kl} = \sum_i [A]_{(i, k)} E^{il}, $$
Showing that $T_{il, kl} = [A]_{(i, k)}$, and that $T_{ij, kl} = 0$ when $j \neq l$, the same result as before.